# Error trying to deploy to firebase due to functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am getting an error trying to deploy to firebase due to functions.

Firebase deploy functions grpc Error.. Windows 7, Angular cli 1.6, Node v 9, npm -s 3 X

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.6.6/node-v59-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.6.6 and node@9.3.0 (node-v59 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
D:\websites\website\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\grpc\build\WINDOWS_BUILD_WARNING.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\Microsoft.Cpp.D
efault.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

What am I doing wrong? Can this be an issue due to node version?

Comment: how are you deploying?

Comment: This is what I get now ```i  deploying database, storage, firestore, functions, hosting
i  functions: running predeploy script.
npm ERR! missing script: build``` And am deploying , just with ```firebase deploy```