# 404 page not found when running firebase deploy

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I have built a stunning web app using react and Google's firebase for `auth` and for database. On my local server, everything runs well. I can authenticate certain users and navigate to the next page upon a successful login. The problem starts when deploying my web app using firebase hosting.

So, first installed the `firebase-tools` then ran `npm run build` after that  I initialized firebase (i was logged in). Then I ran `firebase deploy`. After answering the prompted questions, a [URL](https://my-tutor-d4133.firebaseapp.com/) to my supposedly working site was given to me.

Now when I log in using the details that should successfully log me in, I get the error below:

> 404
>   Page Not Found
>   The specified file was not found on this website. Please check the URL for mistakes and try again.
>   Why am I seeing this?
>   This page was generated by the Firebase Command-Line Interface. To modify it, edit the 404.html file in your project's configured public directory.

To see this error live, here is [the link](https://my-tutor-d4133.firebaseapp.com)

Part of the code that should navigate the user to the next page after successful log in is shown below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fire from './Firebase';
import List from './components/List';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((u)=>{
        window.location = 'list'; 
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        alert("You don't have priviledges to log in!")
      });
  }
```

Here is code snippet in the firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```

The error from functions:

```
=== Deploying to 'my-tutor-d4133'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /home/superlelo/Desktop/myTutor/mytutor/functions
> eslint .

sh: 1: eslint: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/superlelo/.npm/_logs/2019-09-26T21_15_49_018Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

I am not sure of how to fix this, could someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect your `hosting -> public` entry in the `firebase.json` file is not pointing to the directory you built to. If you're building a single-page-app with React, double check you have a `rewrites` entry to redirect all requests to `index.html`.

Comment: @JeremyW  Thanks, I am not sure if I am doing the double checking in the right way. How do I do what you say I should do, how do I " double check I have a rewrites entry to redirect all requests to index.html"

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58096096/edit) your post and include the contents of your `firebase.json` file, I'll add an answer explaining it.

Comment: Also, in your `package.json` file, what does your `build` script do? Include that in your edit too please. Are you using CreateReactApp?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your `firebase.json` file's `hosting->public` entry is correctly pointed to the `build` directory. That's good. That's the [output directory for Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment). Unless you intentionally changed where CRA builds to, Firebase should be deploying whatever is in that `build` folder.

Since you want the routing to occur on the client - handled by React - you need the backend (Firebase) to serve up your React website for ALL routes requested. You do that by adding a `rewrites` section to your configuration:

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: so - I had to add admin privileges using functions and I came across that last added error. I ran 'firebase deploy --only functions` , do you know a work around it?

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48603033/8026947)?

Comment: I have tried all those options, but none of them works. Have you worked with functions enough to anticipate a probable cause and work through?

Comment: Not with that error. I recommend you post a separate question for this problem, someone might have a solution you haven't found. Make sure you list what you've tried in the new question :) Good luck!

Comment: It was indeed the `/` at the start of `index.html` that fixed it for me, thanks