# How to fix an 404 error when directly typing in the url in the browser (react-router-dom)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to let users access specific pages when typing in for example [www.page-url.com/about-us](http://www.page-url.com/about-us) instead of going via [www.page-url.com](http://www.page-url.com) and then choose about us in the nav bar. When I type in [www.page-url.com/about-us](http://www.page-url.com/about-us), I get a 404 error (page not found). How can this action be prevented? I have tried different solutions from questions here on SO, but none of them worked.

Router code:

```
<Router >
        <MobileNavbar />
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
          <Route path='/om-oss' component={AboutUs} />
          <Route path='/sponsorar' component={Sponsor} />
          <Route path='/bli-sponsor' component={BecomeSponsor} />
          <Route path='/bli-medlem' component={BecomeMember} />
          <Route path='/admin' exact component={Admin} />
          <Route path='/admin-login' exact component={AdminLogin} />
          <Route path="/admin/bytt-passord" exact component={ChangeCreds} />
          <Route path="/admin/medlemer" exact component={Members} />
          <Route path="/til-foreldre" component={Parents} />
          <Route path="/kalendar" component={Calendar} />
          <Route path="/admin/kalendar" exact component={AdminCalendar} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
```

Comment: How is your app hosted? If you are using nginx, you have to configure your server to point the request to your SPA index html

Comment: Do you want to prevent showing 404 error pages? In your current router configs, please take an example

Comment: I host my app via Firebase hosting to a domain bought here in Norway. I want to let users access for example the About us-page with typing in www.page-url.com/about-us, but when I do this, I get a 404 page not found-error.

Comment: you are getting the 404 error because it don't see any route which is matching the path `/about-us`

Answer (score 0):

When the user types some route which you are not supporting then you can have a catch all Route. Add this at the bottom of your **Switch** .

```
<Route path='*'><SomeComponent /></Route>
```

[Catch All Routes](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-wood-785ub?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: But does this let the user to access the About us page with going directly to www.page-url.com/about-us, or does this redirect a user to another component if I do not support the route?

Comment: is will render the <SomeComponent /> .

Comment: Do you have any example of how I can avoid the 404 error when accessing the AboutUs component, in the code above, directly? I tried you solution, but nothing changed.

Comment: I have done exactly what you have done in your code sandbox example, but I still get a 404 error

Comment: did you try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096096/404-page-not-found-when-running-firebase-deploy

Comment: The answer from your link fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: That path, as far as I understand, is to be used for all the other paths that are not present in the App routes.  That is, the not found pages (404).