# while deploying in firebase i got "The specified file was not found on this website. Please check the URL for mistakes and try again."

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, routes

i am currently deploying a react project with firebase
below path i am using

**<Route exact path="/product-type/laptop" element={<Allproductpage type={'Laptop'} />} />**

this is working correctly for localhost but not working well for after deploy. and getting the error page not found .
how to fix it

Answer (score -1):

This user had the same problem as you in this question:
[404 page not found when running firebase deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096096/404-page-not-found-when-running-firebase-deploy)

Looks like there's a problem in your firease.json configuration.