# functions/lib/functions/src/index.ts does not exist, can't deploy Cloud Functions

Tags: json, typescript, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

When I try deploying my Firebase cloud functions I get the following error.

Desired behavior: Deploy functions successfully.

**Error:**

> Error: There was an error reading functions/package.json:
>
> functions/lib/index.js does not exist, can't deploy
> Cloud Functions

**Full log:**

> name@name-MacBook-Pro functions % firebase deploy
>
> === Deploying to 'newtiktok-21570'...
>
> i  deploying functions Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR"
> run lint
>
> functions@ lint /Users/name/Desktop/Yoveo/functions
> eslint "src/**/*"
>
> /Users/name/Desktop/Yoveo/functions/src/index.ts
> 186:67   warning  'timestamp' is defined but never used
> @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars   377:86   warning  'mediaNum' is
> defined but never used     @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars   377:104
> warning  'commentText' is defined but never used
> @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars   377:125  warning  'commentID' is
> defined but never used    @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars   419:119
> warning  'commentID' is defined but never used
> @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars   463:121  warning  'commentID' is
> defined but never used    @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars   520:75
> warning  'mediaNum' is defined but never used
> @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars   732:25   warning  'slap' is
> defined but never used         @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
>
> ✖ 8 problems (0 errors, 8 warnings)
>
> Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build ✔  functions:
> Finished running predeploy script.
>
> Error: There was an error reading functions/package.json:

My p.json:

```
 {
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*\"",
    "build": "",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.8.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.8.1",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Please have a look into this [Official Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48603033/8791788). Please execute **npm install** from functions folder and deploy again. Could you please share your directory structure? Please also have a look into the Firebase Official [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#run_the_emulator_suite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

I was able to solve the problem by removing everything associated with Firebase functions. And running: `firebase init` again. After I `cd functions` run `npm install`. Then I was able to deploy successfully after fixing an error with:

```
    3:26  error    'express' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S express' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies
```

Answer (score 21):

cd into your functions folder and run this command

> npm run-script build

This will create the lib/index.js file that is missing

Answer (score 11):

firebase uses `main` field in `package.json` as program entry point,
set it properly, **probably** like this.

```json
"main": "lib/src/index.js",
```

Comment: This one helped! Thank you

Answer (score 5):

For some reason recently the build flow of firebase functions changed.

It used to be:

```
npm --prefix ./functions install ./functions
firebase deploy --only functions
```

now it is:

```
npm --prefix ./functions install ./functions
npm --prefix ./functions run build
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I have not researched what caused this change, but adding this as build step fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

> functions/lib/index.js does not exist

In case you are working in firebase project that contains a frontend or is structured as a monorepo, **this error may also stem from having accidentally imported a frontend file in the `functions` backend part of the project.** For all files that are not within your functions project scope, the typescript compiler will refuse to compile ts files referencing them. So in this case, the solution is to search for any imports containing `/src/` (or any other paths pointing outside) and remove (or correct) them within your `functions` project.

Comment: In my case, Visual Studio Code's auto-include modified my `tsconfig.json` and added a reference to a file outside of the firebase tree... This indeed caused the problem. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

you just have to change the main inside package.json file from lib/index.js to your index file which is usually under the src folder

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this same issue by following **Felix K** indications, answered on Apr 28, 2021.

> In case you are working in firebase project that contains a frontend or is structured as a monorepo, this error may also stem from having accidentally imported a frontend file in the functions backend part of the project. For all files that are not within your functions project scope, the typescript compiler will refuse to compile ts files referencing them. So in this case, the solution is to search for any imports containing /src/ (or any other paths pointing outside) and remove (or correct) them within your functions project.

In my case, I've accidently imported an interface from the frontend. When updating this import I was able to successfully deploy my function.

**Solution from Edward Amoah Idun:**

> cd into your functions folder and run this command 
> npm run-script build 
> This will create the lib/index.js file that is missing

Yes, but it will create the **index.js** file that is missing **in the wrong folder**. Still necessary to check that you don't have imports from another projects.

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm run build` and it will create the folder lib

Answer (score 0):

Changing the **firebase.json** file to the following fixed my issue:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": ["npm --prefix ./functions run build"],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lib folder is for your built functions code, so you haven't built it. This can be done automatically by adding redeploy code to your firebase.json config file:

```
{
    "functions": [
        {
            "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"],
            // rest of config...
        }
    ]
}
```