# Eslint error when deploying firebase functions

Tags: firebase, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-functions

I've set up and express server to run on firebase cloud functions. Now I'm trying to deploy it to firebase with the CLI using "firebase deploy --only functions" but it fails every time, saying there's an unexpected token. I suspect there's a problem with using async arrow functions in the index.js file, but I'm not sure and I also need them for my project.

Here is the index.js file:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const { response } = require("express");
const stripe = require("stripe")('superlongtestkey')

//app config
const app = express();
//middleware
app.use(cors({ origin: true}));
app.use(express.json());

//api route
app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
    const total = request.query.total;

    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: total,
        currency: "usd"
    });

    response.status(201).send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    });
});
```

Here is the error I get when I try to run firebase deploy --only functions:

> === Deploying to 'homunculus-ad003'...
>
> i  deploying functions Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR"
> run lint
>
> > functions@ lint C:..............\Repos\github\amazonhomunculus\functions
> > eslint .
>
> C:..............\Repos\github\amazonhomunculus\functions\index.js
> 17:56  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! functions@ lint:
> `eslint .` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the
> functions@ lint script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with
> npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:..............\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-07-16T12_20_21_809Z-debug.log
> events.js:291
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
> at notFoundError (C:..............\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
>
> ```
> at verifyENOENT (C:\..............\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
>
> at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\..............\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12) Emitted 'error' event on
> ```
>
> ChildProcess instance at:
> at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:..............\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12) {   code: 'ENOENT',   errno:
> 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
> path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',   spawnargs: [] }
>
> ## Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero
> exit code1

I'm working on a windows machine

Is there a way to bring es7 or later syntax into the server, or another way to deploy to firebase functions???

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to deploy Cloud Functions:

- One is through the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) (not the firebase one), although the firebase options are only in preview mode.
- The other one is through the firebase deploy command. Which is the intended option for firebase based Functions.

To be able to use ES7 or later syntax you can try [Typescript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript). Cloud Functions runtime is [Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) and [Node 14](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions) already supports most of the ES20015-2017 features. So writing on node could be also another option.

And the error seems very similar to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48603033/15972325) and [this Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/822) so it is most likely due to missing some dependencies in the directory or an issue with the pre-deploy linting script. I would try those solutions.